# WPF/Silverlight - Binding Across Multiple XAMLs

Tags: silverlight, binding, prism

.

Hello guys,

Consider the usual scenario of Prism (WPF/Silverlight) in which we've multiple regions, and in each goes a view (XAML), so a situation might arise when we interact with one view (XAML), either using mouse, or keyboard, we may want to change or update other views (which happen to be **different** XAMLs) accordingly. For example, on selecting an item from a view, say **ItemPanelView**, we may want to show the details of the selected item in other view, say **ItemDetailsView**.

So my question is,

Would it be a good idea to bind elements from one view (XAML), to the elements in the other views (**different** XAMLs), to implement such functionalities? If I'm not wrong, using this approach we would not need to go from one presenter to other (using TwoWay bindings etc), so as to update the view in other region.

Or, is there any elegant yet simple way to do this?

.

Comment: Do the views share a view model?

Comment: stocherilac, it may share a view model, or may not. Since I want to make this as flexible as possible, let's consider the case of not sharing a single view model. Instead, each view has it's own view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the Prism's EventAggregator (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/francischeung/archive/2008/06/02/decoupled-communication-with-prism-event-aggregation.aspx).  Each of your views (or preferably view models to which views can respond/update using triggers) can subscribe to / publish a shared event.  However, I suggest that instead of simply responding to a mouse click or keyboard event to raise this shared event, make the shared event meaningful (i.e. MyItemSelected or MyItemHidden).  If you need more assistance or clarification with this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that without breaking canonical concept of the PRiSM. 
As [MSDN docs][1] (Chapter 9: Communicating Between Loosely Coupled Components) tell us:

When communicating between modules, it is important that you know the differences between the approaches so that you can best determine which approach to use in your particular scenario. The Prism Library provides the following communication approaches:

```
 Commanding. Use when there is an expectation of immediate action from the user interaction.
 Event aggregation. For communication across view models, presenters, or controllers when there is not a direct action-reaction expectation.
 Region context. Use this to provide contextual information between the host and views in the host's region. This approach is somewhat similar to the DataContext, but it does not rely on it.
 Shared services. Callers can call a method on the service which raises an event to the receiver of the message. Use this if none of the preceding is applicable.
```

In your case you should use EventAggregator or RegionContext. Shared ViewModel is possible but this is the last resort.